# Centos/Redhat XSP4 daemon

Tags: centos, amazon-ec2, redhat-enterprise-linux, asp.net, mono-framework

How can I install xsp to run as a daemon.I run my `/etc/init.d/xsp` script(see below) it stops with status message :

```
Listening on address: 0.0.0.0
Root directory: /var/www/asptest
Listening on port: 8080 (non-secure)
Hit Return to stop the server.
```

I think my Linux AMI is based on Redhat/Centos so there is no start-stop-daemon util in it..
Here is my 
`/etc/init.d/xsp` script:

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          xsp
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs $network
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Asp.Net testing server startup script.
# Description:       Asp.Net testing server startup script.
### END INIT INFO

PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
DESC=xsp
NAME=xsp
DAEMON=/usr/bin/xsp4
DEFAULT=/etc/default/$NAME
DAEMON_ARGS="--nonstop --root /var/www/asptest"
#DAEMON_ARGS="--nonstop --root /usr/lib/xsp/test"
MONO_SHARED_DIR=/var/run/$NAME
PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME

[ -x "$DAEMON" ] || exit 0
[ -f "$DEFAULT" ] && . $DEFAULT

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

if [ ! -e $MONO_SHARED_DIR ]; then
        mkdir $MONO_SHARED_DIR
    chown $user:$group $MONO_SHARED_DIR
fi

chk_start() {
        if [ -f "$PIDFILE" ]; then
                xpid=`head -1 "$PIDFILE"`
                xps=`ps -p $xpid | wc -l`
                if [ "$xps" != "1" ]; then
                        echo -n "Xsp is running"
                        return 1
                fi
        fi
        return 0
}

do_start()
{
        export MONO_SHARED_DIR
        daemon --user $USER --pidfile /var/run/${NAME}.pid $DAEMON --port $port --address $address $DAEMON_ARGS &
}

do_stop()
{
        if [ -e "$PIDFILE" ] ; then
                kill -9 `head -1 "$PIDFILE"` 1>/dev/null 2>&1
            rm -f "$PIDFILE"
        fi
}

case "$1" in
  start)
        if chk_start ; then
                do_start
        fi
        ;;
  stop)
        do_stop
        ;;
  status)
       ;;
  restart|force-reload)
        do_stop
        do_start
        ;;
  *)
        echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {start|stop|status|restart|force-reload}" >&2
        exit 3
        ;;
esac
```

Any help appreciated.